# dynamically displaying scrolling list of characters via FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an array in a file called arrays.js like this:

```
export var Characters = [
    {
    id: 1,
    Name: "Dirk Longsword"
    Avatar: require('./images/profile1.png')
    },
    {
    id: 2,
    Name: "Msal Reaper"
    Avatar: require('./images/profile2.png')
    },
    {
    id: 3,
    Name: "Stone Rockthrow"
    Avatar: require('./images/profile3.png')
    }
]
```

On my main screen, I'm trying to write it all out dynamically via a scrollable  like this:

```
import {Characters} from './arrays';


render() {

    return (
        <FlatList
            data={Characters}
            keyExtractor={
                character => character.Name
            }
            renderItem={
                ({character}) => (
                    <View style={[styles.flexRow]}>
                        <Text>
                            {character.Name}
                        </Text>
                        <Image style={[ styles.charImage ]}
                            source={character.Avatar}
                        />
                    </View>
                )
            }
        />

}
```

But I keep getting this error:

> 'undefined' is not an object(character.Name)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and could use a helping hand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'll be ignoring the many syntax errors in the code you posted.

Second, you are misunderstanding how `{ }` destructuring works in Javascript. You are attempting to destructure `character` from the data passed to `Flatlist`'s `renderItem`. There is no such key value for the object passed to `renderItem`. If you look at [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#renderitem), you'll see there there are only the following keys:

- item <- This contains the "character" object that you are trying to access.
- index
- separators

You can fix your code in two ways. One of which is to not destructure at all:

```
renderItem={
    (character) => (
        <View style={[styles.flexRow]}>
            <Text>
                {character.item.Name}
            </Text>
            <Image style={[ styles.charImage ]}
                source={character.item.Avatar}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

The other is to destructure `item` and use that in the manner you're trying to do with `character`:

```
renderItem={
    ({item}) => (
        <View style={[styles.flexRow]}>
            <Text>
                {item.Name}
            </Text>
            <Image style={[ styles.charImage ]}
                source={item.Avatar}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```